# recursively change file permission but not directories?

Tags: filesystems, permissions, find, chmod

I was doing a mass recursive change of permissions of some files that I had migrated to a unix system. I changed them to ug+rw, but then I found that I could not traverse subdirectories. I looked at the man page for `chmod` and didn't see any explanation for excluding directories, so I googled a little and found that people used `find` to recursively change the permissions on directories to 'execute' for user and group. I did that and then I could look into them.

But it seemed to me that I should be able to be able to do this find `chmod` -- to recursively change the files to read/write but not make the directories untraversable. 
Have I done this the 'right' way or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The better solution should be

```
chmod -R ug=rwX,o=rX /path
```

where the capital `X` means: set execute bit if

> the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user

(quoted from `chmod` man page).

Or also, if you want to use `find`

```
find /path \( -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o=r   {} + \) -o \
           \( -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o=rx {} + \)
```

Comment: I used the wide open for everyone version of this command for my USB hard drive:
chmod -v -R ugo=rwX /path
Thanks!

Comment: Evidently there is no way without using `find` to set all file permissions to 600 and all directory permissions to 700.  (I arrived here through my googlings on the subject.)  If that *can* be done with a single `chmod -R` command, feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Wildcard: not exactly, the command `chmod -R u=rwX,go= /path` does almost what you want: it sets all dirs to 700 and all files to 600 or 700, depending on if the execution bit is already set or not, and I think this is the right thing to do.

Comment: @enzotib, yes—almost, but not quite.  In my case I want to disable the execution bit for *all* files (but not directories of course) regardless of whether they are scripts or binaries or whatever.  So the `find` command you wrote was very helpful as a template.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard what about removing the execute bit first, recursively, then add it back only to directories using the above command?

Comment: @Michael, that would be fairly error-prone as once the execute bit is removed on a directory, you can't access any of the files inside.  So you'd have to ensure you were doing a strictly depth-first search and only removing the execute bit at the deepest level.  Not sure how to do that with `find`; the answer given here is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Using find is the 'right' way, and the only programmatic way, although there are variations:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} +  # "+" may not be on all systems
```

or

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod ug+rw  # similar to the -exec + functionality
```

or the slowest:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;  # in case xargs is not installed
```

Each of these selects a file (not directory, not symlink) and applies the `chmod` command on it.  The first two reduce the number of calls to `chmod` by appending the file to the end of an internal command line each time until a maximum is reached (often 10), then calls the command and starts rebuilding a new command.  The last statement spawns a new process for each file, so it is less efficient.

Comment: POSIX requires `find` to support `-exec` ... `{} +`; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html . On the other hand, it doesn't require `find` to support `-print0`, nor `xargs` to support `-0`.